# Adding custom capability to custom role

Tags: moodle

I'm programming a new block called "custom_block" and I want to add the "custom_capability" to "custom_role". I've tried adding it manually through the web administration tools and it works ok.

Now, I want to add it programmatically to all my Moodle instances, so inside my `blocks/custom_block/db/access.php` looks something like this:

```
'block/custom_block:custom_capability' => array(
        'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM | RISK_XSS,
        'captype' => 'write',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'student' => CAP_PREVENT,
            'teacher' => CAP_PREVENT,
            'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'custom_role' => CAP_ALLOW
        ),
    ),
```

which throws an `error/moodle/invalidlegacy`error, because 'custom_role' is not an archetype (even though they share name with the basic Moodle roles), but there is no alternative "role" field to define this.

So how can I achieve this?

---

Restrictions:

- Custom_role already exists on all the Moodle instances.
- Custom_role doesn't and cannot inherit from an archetype. *"Apply the capability to an archetype and make "custom_role" inherit from the archetype"* works but is not acceptable because the capability would side-effectively be applied to others roles inheriting from it.
- Must be done programatically, think hundreds of Moodle instances.
- It doesn't need to be done through access.php, but must be repeatable and updatable.
- Must "play nice" with Moodle. No hacky SQL manually modifying [mdl_role_capabilities] (I already know hacky SQL), but the answer *"there is no other way but hacky SQL"* would be accepted, lacking any other.
- Compatibility with Moodle 2.8 would be ideal, but missing that, a solution for another (more recent) version would also be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to add something like this to `blocks/custom_block/db/install.php`

```
if ($roleid = $DB->get_field('role', 'id', array('shortname' => 'custom_role') {
    $context = \context_system::instance();
    assign_capability('block/custom_block:custom_capability', CAP_ALLOW,
        $roleid, $context);
}
```